# How to find the QM propagator for more general quadratic theories? (and why didn't my attempts work?)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, path-integral, propagator

**The Problem**

I'm working on a problem using the Path Integral approach to quantum mechanics. Actually, more accurately I'm interested in the Wick rotated version of the problem, so I suppose technically it's a 1D statistical field theory, but that's not the point. The point is that I have integrated out one field in the problem, so that the effective Lagrangian for the remaining field, $x$, despite being quadratic, has non trivial energy dependance. It is presented simplest in Fourier space, where the action is of the form:

$$S[x]=\int \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \frac{a(\omega)}{2b(\omega)} |x(\omega)|^2$$

where $a$ and $b$ are both polynomials in $\omega$. What I'm trying to compute is (equivelant to) the QM propagator (in the sense of the kernel) for this kind of theory.

My first instinct, since it's a quadratic Lagrangian, was to find the classical action given some boundary conditions. I think I'm correct in saying that this is

$$x(\omega)=\sum_ka_k\delta (\omega - \omega_k)$$

where $\omega_k$ are the roots of $a(\omega)$, and $a_k$ are chosen such that $x(t)$ goes through some set of points. Since this is basically a higher derivative theory, I was of course expecting to need to specify more points than just the start and end, but I'm struggling with the step of substituting this back in. It looks like I'd have to integrate the square of some delta functions multiplied by a function that is zero at all the points that the deltas are non-zero?

**What Else I've Tried**

I tried leaning into the SFT analogy. In that picture, the probability of a path is

$$P(path)\propto exp(-S[path]).$$

Because I have a quadratic Lagrangian, this looks suspiciously like a multivariate normal distribution over a continuum of variables corresponding to the different frequencies. The precision matrix would be $\frac{a(\omega)}{b(\omega)}2\pi \delta(\omega-\omega')$, and this is diagonal so the the covariance matrix would be $\frac{b(\omega)}{a(\omega)}2 \pi\delta(\omega-\omega')$ (=the propagator in the other sense!).

My understanding was that the probability that the path taken coincides with a few observations at a few points, i.e. $x(t_k)=x_k$, could be found up to a normalisation by marginalising out all other points in the multivariate normal. This is well known to just involve dropping them from the covariance matrix (and mean vector) so all I would have to do is Fourier transform back:

$$\Sigma(t)=FT^{-1}[\frac{b(\omega)}{a(\omega)}](t).$$

And I would find that $x_k$ would be distributed in a multivariate normal distribution with vanishing mean, and covariance matrix $\Sigma_{jk} = \Sigma(t_j-t_k)$, but I've tried this out, and I don't think it works. For instance, in the free particle case, I find that $\Sigma(t)\propto|t|$, so given only two points, I would expect
$$\Sigma_{jk} \propto \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \Delta t\\
\Delta t & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
and $$\Sigma^{-1}_{jk} \propto \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1/\Delta t\\
-1/\Delta t & 0
\end{array}\right).$$
The well known heat kernel instead implies $P(xy)\propto exp(-\frac{m(x-y)^2}{2\Delta t})$. To it's credit, this means my method got the cross terms right, but fails for the variances. This seems to be true for the other examples I tried too, like the harmonic oscillator.

Any idea how to approach this properly, and why my attempt failed?

Answer (score 4):

You can write your action as
\begin{equation}
S = \frac{1}{2} \int  \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \int \frac{d\omega'}{2\pi} x(\omega') K(\omega, \omega') x(\omega)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
K(\omega,\omega') = \frac{a(\omega)}{b(\omega)} \delta(\omega-\omega')
\end{equation}
This can be formally rewritten as a matrix equation, where $x$ is a vector and $K$ is a matrix
\begin{equation}
S = \frac{1}{2} x^T K x
\end{equation}
The propagator is then the inverse of $K$. One way to see this is by computing the path integral with a
\begin{equation}
Z[J] = \int Dx e^{i \left(S[x] + \int d\omega x(\omega) J(\omega)\right)} = e^{-\frac{i}{2} J^T K^{-1} J}
\end{equation}
where $K^{-1}$ appears in the place that the propagator appears in a quadratic theory.

So the propagator is
\begin{equation}
G(\omega) = \frac{b(\omega)}{a(\omega)}
\end{equation}
As an example, a standard theory would have $b=1$ and $a=\omega^2+m^2$. Using the formula above would yield the standard propagator, $G(\omega)=\left(\omega^2+m^2\right)^{-1}$.

However, you should be aware that for general $a(\omega)$ and $b(\omega)$, you can easily run into issues such as having a non-local theory, [Ostragradski ghosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrogradsky_instability), or violating unitarity bounds on amplitudes such as the [Froissart bound](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Froissart_bound).

Comment: Apologies if it wasn't clear, but I'm looking for the propagator in the **Quantum Mechanics** sense, a.k.a the kernel, a.k.a the position representation of the time evolution operator. In fact I even mentioned when the propagator in this, the QFT sense turned up in my attempted solution.

Comment: @TomLowe I don't understand what distinction you are making. You can also use path integral methods in quantum mechanics.

Comment: It isn't just my own distinction. Consider your own example, essentially the harmonic oscillator. The propagator in the QFT sense is indeed $(\omega^2 + m^2)^{-1}$, but in the QM sense, the propagator is the [Mehler kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel).

Comment: @TomLowe In that case you could choose $a(\omega)$ appropriately. For example, to get the free Schrodginer equation, you would choose $a(\omega)=\omega + k^2$ (where $k$ is the spatial wavenumber), and you would have a nonrelativistic propagator $(\omega+k^2)^{-1}$.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your comment, you're suggesting a Lagrangian density like $\dot{\psi}\psi + (\partial_x \psi)^2$. While this is a theory who's classical limit looks like a Schrodinger equation, it is absolutely not to be interpreted the same way. For starters it is in 1+1D (at least), whereas quantum mechanics is formulated as fields only over time (0+1D). If you'd like a refresher on this exact example, see section 1.1.2 of [Tong's fantastic QFT notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf#sec1.1.2)

Comment: @TomLowe You're asking a trivial mathematical question about inverting diagonal linear operators.  *Of course* first and second quantization are different things but that's just not relevant for your question. You can read more about non-relativistic propagators here, and you can see it amounts to inverting the linear operator that comes out of the procedure in my answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Non-relativistic_propagators. Anyway, good luck finding the help you need here.

Comment: I'm really not. It's become clear to me that you don't understand my question, or the distinction between two senses in which people use the word "propagator".

Comment: @TomLowe I think what you're getting at by "quantum mechanics propagator" is "inverse of the Schrodinger equation." Fair enough, that's not the same thing as the "inverse of the classical equations of motion." But there is nothing that's specifically "quantum mechanics" about it -- there is also a Schrodinger functional in QFT. Anyway, the mathematical methods are exactly the same for computing the propagator in both cases, even if the physical interpretation is different. This chapter explains things: https://eduardo.physics.illinois.edu/phys582/582-chapter10-edited.pdf. See Eq 10.48.

Comment: Now you're getting the idea. Only in QM contexts is this usually called the propagator as in QFT the word is reserved for the other thing. Anyway, your link gives a method I was familiar with. Obviously it doesn't apply directly. As it's effectively a higher derivative theory defining a Hamiltonian isn't easy. For concreteness try the case after integrating one QHO out of a system of two coupled: $a\propto(w^2-w_0^2)(w^2-w_1^2)-\lambda^2$, $b=(w^2 -w_1)^2$. Can you manage it? There also should be a way without finding the Hamiltonian since for quadratic actions $K\propto e^{-S[x_{classical}]}$